# How to import FSCalendar using SwiftUi?

Tags: swiftui, swift5, xcode11, fscalendar

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FSCalendar

class calendars: UIViewController, FSCalendarDelegate{
    var calendar = FSCalendar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calendar.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        calendar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.width)
        view.addSubview(calendar)
    }
}

struct CalendarView: View {
    var body: some View{
            calendars()
    }
}
```

I don't really know is it correct to swiftui but I got an error said `Return type of property 'body' requires that 'calendars' conform to 'View'` 
I just wanna import a calendar and some kind of to do list.

Comment: Search & read about `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.. it helps I mean really

Comment: This can be customisable as you want -> https://github.com/yodagamaheshan/DateGrid

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to include FSCalendar into SwiftUI is to wrap it in an UIView:

```
struct CalendarView: UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    return FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 40.0, width: .infinity, height: 300.0))
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
}
}
```

Usage in SwiftUI code:

```
CalendarView()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it..

```
struct CalendarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CalendarController>) -> calendars {
        return calendars()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: calendars, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CalendarController>) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I am unable to find this approached. If possible kindly share full code snippet to used. Also drag to select date feature

Comment: could you share your full code to make FSCalendar work with UIViewControllerRepresentable?